# Where to save project related text files?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, file, path

For testing and debugging purposes, I just hard-coded the file paths for the text files that would be used by my application, e.g.

```
const string CONFIG_FILE_PATH = @"C:\myconfigfile.txt";
```

But I don't think it's a good idea to leave it as it is in the Beta/Release version.

So I am wondering, what would be the best location for saving these configuration files that will be used / read by the application? Any suggestions?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not save the strings in the Settings section of your project? GRight click on your project in Solution Explorer, select Properties, go to the Settings section and add a new string with your file path. Then, in your code, you can access it like this:

```
using ProjectName.Properties;

var path = Settings.Default.MySetting;
```

To change the setting:

```
Settings.Default.MySetting = newPath;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: you mean the `app.config` file? Hmm what's good with saving into that file?

Comment: @woodykiddy that's what it's there for. It's built in, you can modify it's contents both from you code or directly by modifying the app.config file and it's convenient.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds great. I will give it a go.

Comment: 1 more question, since my config file pretty much just contains some values, do you think it'd be good to put these values in the `app.config` and save them as the string? So in that way, I probably don't even have to create the text file at all. What's your opinion? Thanks.

Comment: @woodykiddy I don't really see why not. I use config files quite often, both for strings and for numerical data. It would be easier than having to deal with extra files (no need to check if they exist, no extra IO operations). Just don't overdo it :).

Comment: Thanks buddy, you are great! So app.config it is. I will make some modifications in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder as the executable.

But you should consider using a Settings class (you can read more [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/settings-visual-studio)). Visual Studio can automatically create a strongly typed wrapper around a section in the app.config file.
The settings are stored in the same file as the executable, but can be overridden (and saved from the application) in a matching file in the user profile for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: If the test config file is intended to sit along side your executable, you can "Add" "Existing Item..." to your project and then change its properties to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer".  During debugging, the executable should be able to find the copy of the config in its current working directory.

This isn't such a useful solution when there's a lot of testing to do.

Answer (score 0):

For settings I would certainly use the app.config file. This is proposed by Microsoft and apart from that it is pretty much the easiest way to handle application settings anyway.

For other files I'd recommend either the applications local or roaming settings path, depending on weather you only need the data local or not. For compact, local databases I tend to use this approach. The application directory, as suggested by Albin, is a bad idea. You cannot be sure that the user is actually allowed to write to that directory and/or files in that directory (i.e. the app was pre-installed by an admin with elevated rights).

To get the location of the local paths use

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)
```

and for the roaming path

```
 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming)
```

More information on Windows User Profiles (the actual paths in different versions of Windows for example, you can find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372123.aspx